# I am getting this red mark on project launch icon in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

[image]

Why i am getting this error, i just converted my project from eclipse to android studio. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is some error in your  project files This indicates you are not able to run project before solving that errors.

Comment: @Dilpali Shah i can run the project.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you did wrong(no Code) but you can create a new Androidstudio Project and than copy manually the Files.

Comment: @Nikhil Ok. Are you getting errors in a new Project?

Comment: no errors, but it is showing that red mark on app launcher why?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/error-in-android-studio-emulator-not-running

Comment: Maybe it's a gradle sync Error. Try gradle sync. Or you can configure the default App: when you Click on this redmark you can try maybe some settings. But after that i have no more ideas.